# Java RegEx Trouble: Matching Function Body

Tags: java, regex

having quite some trouble with the following regex.

```
String fktRegex ="public double " + a+ "2" + b + "(double value) {return value * (.*);}\n";
```

a and b are Strings that are inserted individually.

The regex works just fine until I want to identify also the number with it. That's the (.*) part...
Any help`? Would be really glad! Thanks.

C.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the text you are searching in and a copy of the compiled regular expression please?

Comment: public double abc2xyz(double value) {return value * 100000;}
However the datetype could be any numberbased datatype
The text is a java sourcefile obviously.
Don't know what u mean with compiled regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your example I think you need to escape few regex meta-characters like `{` `}` `(` `)` `*` so your regex should probably look more like

```
"public double " + a + "2" + b + "\\(double value\\) \\{return value \\* (.*);\\}\n";
```

---

Demo

```
// abc2xyz
String a = "abc";
String b = "xyz";

String fktRegex = "public double " + a + "2" + b + "\\(double value\\) \\{return value \\* (.*);\\}\n";

String data = "public double abc2xyz(double value) {return value * 100000;}\n";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(fktRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);

if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}else{
    System.out.println("no match found");
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks!!! The only thing is now, that I the number back but I was planning to replace the whole function...?

Comment: @Chaoz77 I am not sure what you are trying to say (maybe its because my English is not too good yet). Try to describe it more or maybe even create another/separate question.

Comment: Sorry... Typo due to lacking browser...
I was asking if there's a way to replace the whole function? The way u described it, i get back only the number. I don't want to extract the factor but the whole function and replace it with my regex.

Comment: @Chaoz77 if you want to get entire match then instead of group(1) use group(0) or just group(). Group 1 is the part between first parenthesis so part in regex so `(.*)` that is after `return value \\* `. If you would like want to lets say find entire return then you should probably use something like `\\{(return value \\*.*;)\\}` and now group 1.